# ansible playbook to delete multiple file with search pattern

Tags: linux, ansible

Using Ansible, how would I delete all items like those below

```bash
rm -rf /var/log/messages-*      
rm -rf /var/log/mail-*
rm -rf /var/log/secure-*
rm -rf /var/log/cron*
rm -rf /var/log/spooler-* 
rm /var/log/up2date-*  
rm /var/log/maillog-*
```

my playbook is running without any error but it is not deleting log files

```yaml
- hosts: all
  #remote_user: my id
  become: yes
  any_errors_fatal: false

  tasks:

   - name: take backup of syslog
     command: cp -pr /etc/logrotate.d/syslog /opt/syslog.bkp

   - name: Update syslog logrotate
     ansible.builtin.copy:
       src: /etc/ansible/sam/syslog_rhel7_8
       dest: /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
       owner: root
       group: root
       mode: '0644'

   - name: Delete old log-files
     command: "{{item}}"
     with_items:
      - rm -rf /var/log/messages-*
      - rm -rf /var/log/mail-*
      - rm -rf /var/log/secure-*
      - rm -rf /var/log/cron*
      - rm -rf /var/log/spooler-*
      - rm /var/log/up2date-*
      - rm /var/log/maillog-*
```

Comment: please format your code properly. cannot understand what it does

Comment: This is more of a SuperUser question than a stackoverflow question.

Comment: I recommended to not use `command` module and not `rm`, but `file` module instead. Furthermore, you'll need `with_flieglob` instead too.

Answer (score 0):

Read the commands from [strings](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sh). For example, given the tree

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/ansible/log/
/tmp/ansible/log/
├── mail-01
├── mail-02
├── mail-03
├── messages-01
├── messages-02
└── messages-03

directories, 6 files
```

the below task

```yaml
    - command: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - sh -c 'rm /tmp/ansible/log/messages-*'
        - sh -c 'rm /tmp/ansible/log/mail-*'
```

works as expected

```yaml
TASK [command] ***************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=sh -c 'rm /tmp/ansible/log/messages-*')
changed: [localhost] => (item=sh -c 'rm /tmp/ansible/log/mail-*')
```

The files will be removed

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/ansible/log/
/tmp/ansible/log/

0 directories, 0 files
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is shown in the following minimal example

```bash
~/test$ mkdir -p var/log/
~/test$ touch var/log/messages-0{1..9}
~/test$ touch var/log/mail-0{1..9}
```

and playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Delete old log files on Remote Node
    file:
      path: "{{ item }}"
      state: absent
    loop: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.fileglob', 'var/log/messages-*') | split(',') }}"
```

which will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Delete old log files on Remote Node] ***************************************
ok: [test2.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-02)
changed: [test1.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-02)
ok: [test2.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-07)
changed: [test1.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-07)
ok: [test2.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-09)
ok: [test2.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-01)
changed: [test1.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-09)
ok: [test2.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-03)
ok: [test2.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-08)
changed: [test1.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-01)
ok: [test2.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-04)
ok: [test2.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-06)
changed: [test1.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-03)
ok: [test2.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-05)
changed: [test1.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-08)
changed: [test1.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-04)
changed: [test1.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-06)
changed: [test1.example.com] => (item=/home/ansible_user/test/var/log/messages-05)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************
test1.example.com  : ok=1    changed=1
test2.example.com  : ok=1    changed=0
```

Adopt and adjust for your needs.

**Documentation**

- [`file` module – Manage files and file properties](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html)
- [`fileglob` lookup – list files matching a pattern](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html)